# displaying checkmarks for the selected cells after adding new cell - Swift

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` with `UITableViewCell`'s and once i select a cell it will display a checkmark for that cell until here its fine, but once i press the add button to add a new cell to that `UITableView` it will take me to another `ViewController` to write the text of the new cell and add it, so after adding it it will take me to the previous `UITableView` but without displaying the checkmarks to the cells that i have already selected before adding the new cell, is there a way to display checkmarks for the selected cells after pressing the back button from the other controller ?

Note: I am using Xcode with swift language to build my application.

Answer (score 0):

The cells in your tableView is made with a array of some Object. In that Object you need to add a variable `isChecked`, and if it true, the tableviewcell at that indexpath will be checked.

you can do so by adding something like this in `cellforrowatindexpath`

```
if objectAtIndexPath.isChecked {
    cell.accessoryType = .Checkmark
} else {
    cell.accessoryType = .None
}
```

So the key is to have a have a variable in the object you are using to populate the viewcontroller.

When you create the new item, you simple say `isChecked = true`, and then add it to the array which contains the items, and it will be checked automatically.